# Unix script changing directory

Tags: unix, sh

I am in root directory, i am creating a script that will take me from root > Home > Logs and inside logs delete 3 log files.
Script will check if they exist, if YES it will delete it.
I am facing some syntax problems if you could help.

Thanks

**My code:**

```
#!/bin/sh
cd Home/Log
if [ -e error1.log ]
then
rm error1
fi
if [ -e error2.log ]
then
rm error1
fi
if [ -e error3.log ]
then
rm error1
fi
```

when i execute the file in root using `./delete` here is what is am getting as errors:

```
$ ./delete
: No such file or directoryme/Log
./delete: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```

Comment: Are you sure the exists such a path `Home/Log` is the current directory when you run the script?

Comment: yes i created it myself

Comment: What happens if you run the commands one by one in the shell, manually?

Comment: can do that, but via script its not working

Comment: And you use the *exact* same commands manually from the shell and in the script? No difference in e.g. capitalization at all? Remember that Unix is case-sensitive.

Comment: You're `rm`ing `error1` for each case of `-e error[123].log`. You need to specify the correct filename to `rm` including the `.log` part of fName. AND an error message that says `No such file or directoryme/Log` is not lying. So the code you have shown us is not the code you are running at your command prompt AND the "missing `fi`" message indicates again you're not showing us the code you are trying to run. Did you try checking your code at http://shellcheck.net `? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am in root directory

When writing a script, it's almost always better not to assume things like that.  If you know where the files are and it's not important that they're somewhere relative to what happens to be your current working directory, just name them.

Here are three ways you could accomplish what you want safely.

```
#!/bin/sh
dir=/Home/Log
rm -f ${dir}/error1.log ${dir}/error2.log ${dir}/error2.log
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
dir=/Home/Log
rm -f ${dir}/error{1,2,3}.log
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cd /Home/Log && rm -f error1.log error2.log error2.log
```

For anything nontrivial, `set -e` is your friend.  In your example, nothing happens later in the script.  What you don't want is to keep going *thinking* you've changed directories, but haven't, and wind up scribbling somewhere you didn't intend.  Many have lost much that way.